# Why I have "pops" in my vocal

Tags: technique, voice, vocal-cords

I recently noticed when I'm singing I have "pops" like Popcorn in my voice.
I've never had this before, what is that "pops"? It's normal?

Here's example

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1THjLjHHvBc_YvHX38-JSi6hfgmYAJJAl/view?usp=sharing

(0:07-0:10 I can hear it strong)

Comment: This is a bad way to seek medical advise.  Have you ever taken voice lessons or are you just winging it?

Comment: I started to take a voice lessons a month ago

Comment: I'd ask your teacher.  Are you studying with a classical vocal coach?  The "popping" could be spit built up in your throat, a cold coming on, or even poor sound quality due to improper technique.  So in some sense it may be "normal" for a beginner but it isn't "normal".  You need to have your teacher listen and try and figure out what is happening.  Is there pain too?

Comment: My teacher is main foucsed on Jazz and Pop genres, At last lesson she heard the "pops" and tell me that's good and clean my throat but I don't know if my teacher is a good teacher

Comment: I do not want to slander your teacher.  There is not enough info in your question to really evaluate.  And the term "pop" may mean different things to different people.  Did your teacher tell you how to clean your throat out?  I have studied classical/jazz vocal for a couple years and would not claim to be an expert.  But my teacher would not call that sound "normal" or "good".  Barring spit build up, allergies, or a cold, it would mean poor technique, no support and possible strain on the vocal cords.

Comment: This question is old but, is your condition persistent? If this is accompanied by throat pain or vocal fatigue then, you should see a doctor...

Comment: I have a doctor appointment on Tuesday

Comment: @user1569766 Allowing you still remember after two years, ... curious to know what your doctor said and whether you found an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Does not sound healthy to me. I have also had similar problems with my voice "rattling" etc. and **have always narrowed it down to my poor singing technique.** Even if I have a flu, I can make my singing better by utilizing the healthy singing technique and I have got rid of the rattling and other problems by developing my technique and weekly training.

It is important that you train your muscles (facial muscles also, in addition to your body) when you develop your singing technique. You will need a good teacher for this, best teachers are those who have had problems with their singing in their past and got past the problems by developing technique.

Comment: So I was at doctor, my vocal cords are fine but I have a lot of runny nose that making the "pop sound" and harder me to sing